# SQL Migration Script: Insert into, but multiple Select From

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a table and I basically want a nested loop. I have the following, suggested code:

```
with Permissions (Id) as
(
    select Id from Surge.Permission  where Name in (
        'Web.Orders:Enable',
        'App.Orders:Enable',
        'Web.Orders:View',
        'App.Orders:View',
        'Web.Orders:Modify',
        'App.Orders:Modify',
        'Web.Orders:View.All',
        'App.Orders:View.All'
    )
)

insert Surge.[RolePermission] (DataPartitionId, PermissionId, RoleId)
select DP.Id, Permissions.Id, 2 from Surge.DataPartition as DP
```

This doesn't seem right, though (and LINQPad doesn't seem to like it; it can't seem to find `Permissions.Id`). How would I do this with regular SQL? Basically, I want the output to be:

```
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 2,
1, 3, 2
...
2, 1, 2
2, 2, 2
2, 3, 2
```

and so on, like a nested loop.

Comment: What's the purpose of the cte? You're not referencing it in your insert/select statements.

Comment: @GoatCO I've edited the code. I had some mistakes in there and I might have mistakenly copied part of the original snippet my coworker gave me.

Comment: Your edit got rid of the pesky (id,2), but still doesn't reference the cte in the select.

Comment: you got `Permissions.Id` in your `select` but don't have it in `FROM or JOIN` clause

Comment: Uh, I'm not actually seeing that. A find in my browser isn't seeing it either. Where are you seeing `cte`?

Comment: `with Permissions` that is called CTE

Comment: The SQL WITH construction is a Common Table Expression (CTE).

Comment: How are `Surge.DataPartition` and `Surge.Permission` related to each other?

Comment: @KarlKieninger Oh! I see, learned something new today. I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: @GoatCO They aren't, actually. This is for a migration script; I'm adding new permissions throughout our codebase, and they need to be added for all of our datapartitions. However, those two tables have no direct link; the intermediate many-to-many table between Roles and Surge.Permissions has a link to the Surge.DataPartition, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazarding a guess based on your sample data that you want EVERY combination of `Permission.ID` and `DataPartition.ID`:

```
with Permissions as
   (select Id 
    from Surge.Permission  
    where Name in ('Web.Orders:Enable',
                   'App.Orders:Enable',
                   'Web.Orders:View',
                   'App.Orders:View',
                   'Web.Orders:Modify',
                   'App.Orders:Modify',
                   'Web.Orders:View.All',
                  'App.Orders:View.All'
                  )
     )
INSERT INTO Surge.[RolePermission] (DataPartitionId, PermissionId, RoleId)
SELECT DP.Id, p.Id, 2 
FROM Surge.DataPartition as DP
CROSS JOIN Permissions p
```

If that's not the case, you can change the `CROSS JOIN` to another `JOIN` type and add criteria.

Comment: This worked! I tried a JOIN statement before, but ran into some issues - I guess I did something wrong. Cross join worked perfectly, though. Thank you!